# Can't communicate with helper application Xcode simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Sometimes when I try to run my app in the Xcode simulator Xcode gives me an error message: `Couldn’t communicate with a helper application.`

**What can I do to stop this?**

Sometimes it will work for a bit, usually after a restart or changing simulators. I have tried quitting/closing both Xcode and the simulator, and restarting my computer, in various combinations.

I've googled the error but everything I can find isn't about the simulator (its usually about logging in with an Apple ID).

Error details:

```
Couldn’t communicate with a helper application.
Domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain
Code: 4099
Recovery Suggestion: Try your operation again. If that fails, quit and relaunch the application and try again.
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-07-18 23:16:32 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    NSDebugDescription = "The connection to service named com.apple.lsd.installation was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 32 - Broken pipe.";
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone14,5";
    "device_osBuild" = "15.5 (19F70)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = "x86_64";
    "operation_duration_ms" = 25184;
    "operation_errorCode" = 4099;
    "operation_errorDomain" = NSCocoaErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_swiftVersion" = "5.6.1";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphonesimulator15.5";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "15.5";
    "sdk_variant" = iphonesimulator;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 12.4 (Build 21F79)
Xcode 13.4.1 (20504) (Build 13F100)
Timestamp: 2022-07-18T19:16:32-04:00
```

**EDIT:**
This usually happens after I try to rerun a widget extension (followed by a SafariBookmarksSyncAgent quit when I close the simulator).

**EDIT:**
This also occurs on macOS Monterey 12.5 (21G72).

Comment: Same issue is sometimes observed when you right click on a `UITest` and select `Run Repeatedly`

Comment: Reported to Apple: https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/11378058

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't make it work forever, but it will work when I reset the simulator.